# Correct usage of countless hours

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the correct usage in this case:

A:

> Say goodbye to all the tedious manual steps and countless of hours spent finding and correcting code errors.

B:

> Say goodbye to all the tedious manual steps and countless hours spent finding and correcting code errors.

C:

> Say goodbye to all the tedious manual steps and countless hours of time spent finding and correcting code errors.

C feels wrong, isn't time implicit? According to Google "countless hours" got more hits. To me, "countless of hours" sounds better in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B is the best option.

Countless is an adjective ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/countless?s=t)), so it simply goes before the noun it modifies.  You wouldn't have "several of hours" or "long of hours", and the same goes for "countless of hours".

The word "hours" always defines a length of time.  So "hours of time" is just unnecessary.

So A is wrong, and C is just pointlessly wordy.